# Moodle purge all cache freeze the website

Tags: moodle

I am working in moodle website, my client have a lot of comments about performance
I have logged in the website and then use the default Boost theme
I got the following

[image]
[image]
[image]

I click on Purge all cache and then all website is keep loading and freeze

can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Please go to `XAMPP-Cotroll` and open `Apache->Config->httpd.conf` and add

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
   ThreadStackSize 8888888
</IfModule>
```

[Reference Link](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=387587)